# Работа с процентами python

Tags: python, математика

Есть два числа, например: 40 и 50

В результате нужно получить на сколько процентов, первое число больше или меньше второго, то есть:

40 и 50 --- результат: -20%

60 и 50 --- результат: +20%

150 и 50 --- результат: +200%

С математикой все плохо(

Comment: я оставлю намёк: `(40/50 - 1) * 100`

Comment: нужно вычесть из первого числа второе, разделить полученное на второе число, результат умножить на 100

Comment: А ведь действительно, моя сообразительность меня пугает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно составить [пропорцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)):

```
40 - ?

50 - 100%
```

Тогда `? = 40 * 100 / 50` – процент первого числа от второго. Для ответа *на сколько процентов, первое число больше или меньше второго* просто вычитаем из этих полученных процентов проценты второго числа, т.е. всегда `100%` – `40 * 100 / 50 - 100`. Можно вынести `100` за скобки и окончательно получить `(40 / 50 - 1) * 100 = -20`.

Проверим на третьем примере:

```
150 - ?

 50 - 100%
```

Получаем `(150 / 50 - 1) * 100 = 200`.

Таким образом:

```
a, b = int(input()), int(input())

print(a * 100 / b - 100)
```